# Parallel while loop in C#

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, while-loop

I try to write BBS-generator. But this generator is too slow. So I need to parallel while. But i did not how do it. Please help me:).

```
 public static List<BigInteger> GenerateFullCycle(long N, long x0)
{ 
              List<BigInteger> randomNumbers = new List<BigInteger>();
              var bbs = new BBS_generator(N, x0);
              BigInteger rvalue = bbs.Generate();
              while(randomNumbers.Contains(rvalue) == false)
              {
                randomNumbers.Add(rvalue);
                rvalue = bbs.Generate();
              }
              return randomNumbers;
       }
```

Comment: [How to: Write a Simple Parallel.ForEach Loop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460720(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into improving your algorithm first. How large does the `randomNumbers` list get? `Contains` is pretty slow on larger lists. You might want to use a `HashSet` instead.

BBS is slow, as simple as that. Using `BigInteger` really doesn't help at all - also quite slow.

Apart from that, there is no way to parallelize this code. The second iteration on the loop depends on the first, the third on the second etc.. You can parallelize the `GenerateFullCycle` calls themselves, but that's about it.

Parallelization isn't a solve-it-all thing. Many things aren't parallelizable at all - and how much do you get by parallelization? Twice faster? Even if you managed to completely separate and run at 100% efficiency, a 4-core CPU still only means you're four times as fast. True, it does have its applications, but I fail to see how it could help a BBS generator.

And the number one rule of performance tweaking - profile. Where is your application *actually* spending time?

Comment: thank you very much for your answer! I am writing the probalistic cryptoalgorithm. And I have only one problem with bbs generator.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use something like a Background Worker:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx